# how to get the values dynamically in js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hi having problem with my id iam making my website for health product.
already we have a 10 products with corresponding amounts in this section customer choose the product through drop down box.

in next we are getting service charges from customer by clicking radio buttons.

we have a three radio buttons with `name=add` and three amount value like 5$ 7$ 9$.
It is working fine.

for example:
 customer selected 3 produts in the sense that total amount around 20$ after customer clicks this radio button(any) and submit button that amount will add with totally in next page ie 25$

what i want is that radio button amount should add with get payment then display the page dynamically.

```
function checkRadio (frmName, rbGroupName) {
 var radios = document[frmName].elements[rbGroupName];
 for (var i=0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      if(radios[i].checked) {
        return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
          $("input[name='rmr']").click(function() {
           updatePayment($(this).val());
           if (!!$(this).attr("checked") == true) {
             $("#finalamount").html( parseInt($("#totalamount").val(), 10) * parseInt($(this).val(), 10));
         }
     });
}
```

this code  is right or wrong. thanks in adv

Comment: This is your fifth question including source code. It looks like in all four of your previous questions, someone's had to go in and fix the formatting. **Please** take the time to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area. It says quite clearly what to do to format code. There's also the tempting **[?]** link above the Ask a Question box, which provides more detail.

Comment: "this code is right or wrong" I guess you're right about *that* :)

Comment: Yes indeed, the code isn't formatting itself automagically, another human being is doing that for you! I really don't know why I even bother...

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your post that name of Radio buttons are 'add' (ie. name=add)
But below line in your code says that you are matching name=rmr.

```
$("input[name='rmr']").click(function() {
```

Change it to

```
$("input[name='add']").click(function() {
```

Otherwise code seems okay.

Thanks!

Hussain